# How to block audio and video streaming in wireless network

Tags: security, wireless-networking

My wireless connection is frequently getting  disconnected (almost every 5 minutes). I think this is due to audio/video streaming which is used by some users in the wireless network. 
Can you suggest some ways to block this streaming ?

I believe streaming websites uses random port and if we block complete range, it may ultimately use port 80 which would increase the network traffic and resulting in more packet losses. So blocking by port may not be feasible. Can you suggest how to find out which websites are in use currently and how to block them ?

Comment: What kind of router are you using?

Comment: @ I am using Huawei EchoLife HG520s router..

Answer (score 1):

Check your router's QoS settings. You can prioritize the type of traffic you want over anything else with the help QoS rules.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service

Answer (score 0):

Blocking video/audio streaming isn't possible. Just for information, sites like YouTube stream video through port 80. Streaming isn't an advanced protocol. If you want to block specific websites, that's a lot easier. First of all, you have to know your router's local IP address. Once you've found that out, just go to http://127.0.0.1/ for example, or whatever the IP is. There should be a tool on the little page that comes up that allows you to blacklist websites.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 most definitely will not be your router's web page, that's the loopback address. Try 192.168.X.Y (usually 192.168.0.1 if you don't share a gateway)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the disconnects are caused by excessive wireless traffic? If that really is the case I would advice you to take the following steps:

1. Check if the router is not overheating
2. Get a higher quality router, or a standalone acces point

(Blocking streaming only on the wireless side would probably not possible with the equipment you have now anyway.)

However, the disconnects can also be caused by interference from other acces points, wireless phones, microwave ovens or other wireless technology. To check for interference from other acces points you can use a tool like inssider (http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) and see if there are other acces points using the same channel as your acces point. If there is a lot of overlap you should try moving it to an "emptier" channel. Checking for other interference is not so easy however.